# I want to show all active user on index page but always show zero values

Tags: php

I want to show total no of active user status=1 but not show allwayes show 0 value i am using Ci please help me...

```
<?php

      $querya = $this->db->where('status',1);

      $querya = $this->db->get('login'); 

        if ($querya->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                foreach ($querya->result() as $rowi)
                 {
                   $tstatus= $rowi->status;
                 }
            }
            echo $tstatus+0;
     ?>
```

Comment: print your query and check if it is working in phpmyadmin

Comment: What is datatype of `status`? Check with string as well. `$this->db->where('status','1');`

Comment: No need to define `variable` again and again in CI for single query. Update `Query` with
`$this->db->where('status',1); $querya = $this->db->get('login');` Here is full document https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html